# How Azure devops pipeline and branch config together?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How do I create a branch in the Yamal pipeline and then see it in a list of a branch in azure Devops? I can create it but I don't see my branch in a list of branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create new branch during pipeline execution on agent with command like:

```
git checkout -b mynewbranch
```

it stays local on agent where pipeline is running.

To see it in list of branches  you need to [push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) it to your repository:

```
git push --set-upstream origin mynewbranch
```

If you skip this step, new branch will live only on agent where pipeline is executed and will be deleted once job is finished.

Once you push it, you should be able to see new [branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) in results from:

```
git branch -r
```

it will be listed as

*origin/mynewbranch*